# How to make log4j2 custom filter objects work when used context-wide?

Tags: java, filter, log4j2

I'm trying to make a Custom Filter work in the custom-wide level as per [the documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html).
I'm starting to think there's an issue with custom filters when used this way, given the default filters are being called correctly and the custom ones aren't. What I have is:

**ThresholdFilterCustom.java (the same as ThresholdFilter, created to debug only):**

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Marker;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LogEvent;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.Plugin;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginAttribute;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.plugins.PluginFactory;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.filter.AbstractFilter;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.message.Message;

@Plugin(name = "ThresholdFilterCustom", category = "Core", elementType = "filter", printObject = true)
public final class ThresholdFilterCustom extends AbstractFilter {

  private final Level level;

  private ThresholdFilterCustom(Level level, Result onMatch, Result onMismatch) {
    super(onMatch, onMismatch);
    this.level = level;
  }

  public Result filter(Logger logger, Level level, Marker marker, String msg, Object[] params) {
    return filter(level);
  }

  public Result filter(Logger logger, Level level, Marker marker, Object msg, Throwable t) {
    return filter(level);
  }

  public Result filter(Logger logger, Level level, Marker marker, Message msg, Throwable t) {
    return filter(level);
  }

  @Override
  public Result filter(LogEvent event) {
    return filter(event.getLevel());
  }

  private Result filter(Level level) {
    //    Look here! It should always match! not even filtering!
    return onMatch;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return level.toString();
  }

  /**
   * Create a ThresholdFilterCustom.
   * @param loggerLevel The log Level.
   * @param match The action to take on a match.
   * @param mismatch The action to take on a mismatch.
   * @return The created ThresholdFilterCustom.
   */
  @PluginFactory
  public static ThresholdFilterCustom createFilter(@PluginAttribute(value = "level", defaultString = "ERROR") Level level,
      @PluginAttribute(value = "onMatch", defaultString = "NEUTRAL") Result onMatch,
      @PluginAttribute(value = "onMismatch", defaultString = "DENY") Result onMismatch) {
    return new ThresholdFilterCustom(level, onMatch, onMismatch);
  }
}
```

**log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="INFO">
  <Filters>
      <ThresholdFilterCustom level="DEBUG" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />
<!--      <ThresholdFilter level="DEBUG" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />-->
  </Filters>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
    </Console>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="INFO">
      <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

If I uncomment

```
<!--  <ThresholdFilterCustom level="DEBUG" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />-->
```

I don't see the message logged by logger.debug("logmessage") in the console

But if I uncomment

```
<!--  <ThresholdFilter level="DEBUG" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY" />-->
```

I **do** see the messages logged by logger.debug("logmessage"), even though the behavior between them should be identical. Why is this happening? Is it possible this is a log4j2 issue?

Upon using the debugger, I see the filter functions are not even called in the custom filter, but the custom filter is getting instantiated.

They are working correctly if I place them inside a logger. But they aren't working when placing them context-wide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer is [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-3096).

For people that land in here: This got fixed here. In short, it seems that the javadoc of the methods is mixed up. To implement context-wide filters, the other methods should be overriden, the ones that are not filter(LogEvent event).

As per Ralph Goers comments:

> The plugin is being properly constructed and is being called. However,
> you did not override all the filter methods. Most of them default to
> return NEUTRAL, which is what the method did in this case. It probably
> would make more sense to have AbstractFilter default to calling one of
> the other methods so that no so many methods need to be overridden.

His other answer:

> When the global Filters are evaluated a LogEvent has not been
> constructed. So if you want to only support the global filter then you
> need to implement all the methods that don't take a LogEvent.
> Likewise, to use the Filter in other places you need to only implement
> the method that accepts a LogEvent. Yes, I think the Javadoc has it
> backwards.
>
> What I mean with regard to the default methods is that there are 3
> filter methods that explicitly return NEUTRAL.

```
public Result filter(final Logger logger, final Level level, final
Marker marker, final Message msg,final Throwable t); 
public Result filter(final Logger logger, final Level level final Marker 
marker, final Object msg,final Throwable t);
public Result filter(final Logger logger, final Level level, final Marker 
marker, final String msg, final Object... params);
```

> So all 3 of these need to be implemented In a
> Filter such as the one you created. All the other methods that accept
> a Logger end up calling the method above that accepts the varargs
> Object (i.e. an Object array) as the last parameter. It would make
> sense to me that the first 2 methods should also call the third method
> as the default instead of returning NEUTRAL. However, that would mean
> losing the explicit knowledge that one of the parameters was a
> Throwable, which I believe is why it is implemented as it is.  I
> didn't mean that you need to do anything about this, except that right
> now you must implement all 3 methods above.